# How to close all active database connections in one shot?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

While trying to restore SQL Server database or do any other actions which require exclusive database access it displays following error:

> Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
USE master
GO

ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorksDW
SET SINGLE_USER
--This rolls back all uncommitted transactions in the db.
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO

 RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorksDW
 FROM ...
 ...
 GO
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you are asking for, but will terminate all open connections and will rollback uncommitted changes

```
 ALTER DATABASE <yourDB> 
 SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
 GO
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to do would be to put the database in single-user mode.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345598.aspx)

> In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of the SQL Server Database
>   Engine, and then expand that instance. Right-click the database to
>   change, and then click Properties. In the Database Properties dialog
>   box, click the Options page. From the Restrict Access option, select
>   Single. If other users are connected to the database, an Open
>   Connections message will appear. To change the property and close all
>   other connections, click Yes

.

Answer (score 0):

You can [kill all processes](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/kill-all-processes-of-a-database.aspx) that have open connections to a SQL Server database or [alter database to single user mode](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/alter-single-user-multi-user-mode.aspx) with no_wait option

```
ALTER DATABASE [Works] SET SINGLE_USER WITH NO_WAIT
```